# How Server can detect different Serialization classes? C#

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, xml-serialization

How can the Server know which serialized Class is being sent?

Client Side:

```
public void SendCard(Card card)
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Card));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(s, card);
            }
public void SendStage(Stage stage)
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stage));
            ser.Serialize(s, stage);
        }
```

Server side:

```
private void Receive()
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[8192];
            int bytesread;
            s = a_client.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                bytesread = 0;
                try
                {
                    //blocks until a message is read
                    bytesread = s.Read(message, 0, 8192);
                }
                catch (Exception z) { Console.WriteLine(z.Message); break; }
                if (bytesread == 0)
                {
                    // the client has disconnected
                    break;
                }
                //Message successfully received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string smessage = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesread);
                //Somewhere Here needs to detect if message is serialized Card, Stage, or string
            }
        }
```

Like it needs a good if statement or something. And getting error that this post is mostly code.. Hopefully the question is explainable.

Comment: Data is XMLserialized before sending, so it should be XMLDeSerialized using XmlSerializer.Deserialize.

Comment: You are right, but how does the receiving end know which to DeSerialize, the class Card or class Stage if sent by Client?

Comment: I may have a solution to give some thought. if (smessage.Contains("</Stage>)) and if (smessage.Contains("</Card>"))  - basically reading the XML being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a slightly different design pattern, where the class you serialize is always the same, but it contains two properties: one is the class you really want, serialized as a generic object, and the other is a string containing the type of the class you really want.  That way the server/client communication is always the same.

The only caveat to this technique is that both server and client must be referencing the exact same class types, as the XML serialize/deserialize objects must know the class types to serialize/deserialize ahead of time.  From the way you stated your question, I assumed this was OK.

First, some helper classes.  Note the use of XMLInclude - that's the caveat.

```
[Serializable]
public class card
{ }

[Serializable]
public class stage
{ }

[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(card)), XmlInclude(typeof(stage))]
public class serializeHelper
{
    public object Package { get; set; }
    public string PackageType { get; set; }

    public serializeHelper() { } // required for deserialization

    public serializeHelper(object aPackage)
    { 
        Package = aPackage;
        PackageType = aPackage.GetType().FullName;
    }
}
```

And the test code to show how it works.  Here the key trick is the Convert.ChangeType method.

```
        // serialize a helper class containing a card
        // use a local file for the example

        string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);

        serializeHelper toBeSerialized = new serializeHelper(new card());
        XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(serializeHelper));
        xmlSer.Serialize(streamWriter, toBeSerialized);
        streamWriter.Close();

        // deserialize the helper class

        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        XmlSerializer xmlDeser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(serializeHelper));
        serializeHelper wasDeserialized = (serializeHelper)(xmlDeser.Deserialize(streamReader));
        streamReader.Close();

        // get the type, and convert the package to the desired type

        Type t = Type.GetType(wasDeserialized.PackageType);
        object theFinalObject = Convert.ChangeType(wasDeserialized.Package, t);
```

Lastly, if you want the final object to not be of type object or var, you'll have to find the way to do that which will work for you.  VB allows you to use Select Case on a Type, but C# cannot perform switch on a Type.